# How to evaluate whether a method is unbiased in estimating SATE in simulation?

Tags: simulation, treatment-effect

I am trying to understand the concept of sample average treatment effect ($SATE$) over population average treatment effect (PATE). $SATE$ focuses on the effects of treatment in the particular sample we have collected. $PATE$ represents the true treatment effect in the study population.

The main question is how we can show one method (e.g., matching + averaged mean difference, regression) is unbiased in estimating this $SATE$?

Here is the R code generating the sample

```r
set.seed(218)
n = 1000 
x = rnorm(n, 0, 1)

###constant treatment effect ###
t = 0.5

###coefficients for the treatment model ###
a0=-2.2
a1=0.5
lin.p=a0+a1*x
z = rbinom(n,1,exp(lin.p)/(1+exp(lin.p)))

###coefficients for the potential outcome model   ###
### The different errors. SATE will diff from sample to sample###
error1=rnorm(n, 0, 1)
error2=rnorm(n, 0, 1)
y0 = 8 +2*x + error1
y1 = 8 +2*x + t + error2 

data = data.frame(x,z,y0,y1, yi = ifelse(z == 1 , y1, y0))

#SATE for this sample

(SATE = mean(data$y1 - data$y0))
```

Questions:

Q1) If the error is the same for $y_1$ and $y_0$ (i.e., error1=error2), then $SATE$ is constant for every individual and thus equal to $PATE$, right?

Q2) In this particular sample of 1000, $SATE=0.4531$. How can we evaluate whether a method (e.g., matching or regression) is biased or unbiased in estimating $SATE$?  For $PATE$, we can simulate many different samples. For $SATE$, the sample is fixed here. Where can we get that “randomness"? In randomized trial setting, we can reshuffle treatment assignment $z$ in this sample of 1000 observations. Now this is an observational study setting, I doubt it is appropriate.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!